# How should I configure Netty to handle high request volumes?

Tags: java, netty

In our application, we need to build a HTTP server where, upon startup, about 1,600 persistent HTTP connections are opened to it by various remote servers, and a stream of thousands of HTTP POST requests are sent down each connection in quick succession for about 30 seconds - it takes us just a few milliseconds to respond to each one.  After 30 seconds the connection is closed and another is opened.

We selected Netty because by most accounts it is well suited to building efficient HTTP servers.

In implementing our HTTP server, we followed the [Snoop](http://docs.jboss.org/netty/3.2/xref/org/jboss/netty/example/http/snoop/package-summary.html) example of a Netty HTTP server.

Unfortunately we are experiencing problems that may be explained by Netty being overloaded, and so we are reconsidering whether it is properly configured, in particular in the way threads are handled.  We configure the server as follows:

```
ServerBootstrap bootstrap = new ServerBootstrap(
   new NioServerSocketChannelFactory(
            Executors.newCachedThreadPool(),
            Executors.newCachedThreadPool()));
```

When we receive the request we handle it within the same thread that calls messageReceived()  in our SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.

Should this approach work in our application?

*edit:* The load average on the box while the failures are occurring are 0.05, so very low.  I've allocated 4GB to the Java process but it's scarcely using any of it.  So, basically, the box is totally underloaded.

Comment: Can you post some CPU / ram usage figures?

Comment: Responded per your request, the box isn't overloaded.

Comment: What errors are occurring?

Comment: The other service is reporting that it is not receiving our HTTP responses after a 100ms timeout, but our logging shows that we are responding with plenty of time to spare.

Comment: Your last comment seems to point to a problem on the network side, no ? Is the bandwidth large enough ?
Actually I am working on a similar application and I am running into the same type of issue.

Comment: Just curious, are you trying to build an rtb server?

Answer (score 0):

Have you disabled Nagle by setting "child.nodelay" in your ServerBootstrap?

(See http://static.netty.io/3.5/api/org/jboss/netty/bootstrap/ServerBootstrap.html)